# swagger with express nodejs APIs giving 404 error

Tags: node.js, swagger

I have configured swagger for my existing application which is implemented using express nodeJS.

`server.js` placed in the root folder and API's(`*.js` files) inside some other directories like

- modules/data/first.js
- modules/second.js
- modules/config/getConfig.js

In the `server.js` file I declared apis as below

`apis: ["./modules/data/first.js", "./modules/second.js", "./modules/config/getConfig.js"]`

I added `@swagger` in all `.js` files and given

- `/first` for the first.js file
- `/second` for the second.js file
- `/third` for the third.js file

When I open `swagger-UI` page, it is showing 3 APIs but when I click on anyone API then it is giving `404` response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue, problem is due to misconfiguration of `app.use`.

Initially there is no `JWT` token verification, so it worked but later JWT verification was introduced, then I faced `401 error ({"msg": "unauthorized"})` for `swagger-UI` page itself, I made some changes in the swagger options. Then UI page got opened with all endpoints, but when I click on any endpoints they started giving `404` error.

When I changed `app.use` to swagger first and then for my application endpoints it started working.

Comment: this is what I need, just move app use swagger to the first